# Mac after update to OSX Capitan 'gem install' does not work without sudo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, bundler

Just updated my mac to OSX Capitan and `gem install` stopped working without using `sudo`, I use rbenv and did `rbenv rehash` 
but when I run `bundle install` and gives this massage

```
Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system Rubygems.
You can cancel this installation and run:

    bundle install --path vendor/bundle

to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
and install the bundled gems to Rubygems using sudo.
```

How to fix this and make it work as it was before when I could just run `bundle install` or `gem install` to install gems?

**UPDATE**

I Added to

> .bush_profile

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

and run this command in terminal

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

But now every time when I open new terminal window or tab it does not work until I run this command source ~/.bash_profile again in new window or tab

Here is my

> .bashrc

```
alias spec=spec --color --format specdoc
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

How to fix it? What I missed?

Comment: You should never install gems to your system Ruby directory. No doubt permissions have changed.

Comment: Did you update your `.bash_profile` file? did you have it call `eval "$(rbenv init -)"`? can you edit the question and post the file and more information about your environment? I installed rbenv on my el-capitan (a clean install) and it works perfectly...

Comment: I just updated my question with new problem which appeared after editing .bush_profile, could you please give some advise on it?

Comment: You sure you're running bash as your shell?

Comment: You sure you have edited bAsh_profile and not bUsh_profile? )